# Search by date removed from group

Tags: groups, search

I need to rebuild some groups where all the members were removed by the link between CiviCRM and Mailchimp. I have found the ability to list all members of a group who have ever been removed from that group, but I also need to be able to filter this by the date they were removed. Is there any way to search for members of a group who were removed on a specific date?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this functionality exists from the UI or API. I think it's not.

A quick recall says that this info is being stored in `civicrm_subscription_history` table where `contact_id`, `group_id`, `status(Added or Removed)` and `date`(the one when the action was triggered) can be viewed.

Answer (score 3):

I have an extension that provides a custom report [Subscription History](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory) that does this.

Answer (score 2):

For info, the [GDPR extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/gdpr) (first released March 2018) includes a "Search Group Subscription by Date Range" custom search i.e. you can select a group, a group status and importantly a date criteria.

If the rest of the GDPR extension functionality isn't needed, and you're keen and able, the relevant sections of code could be used as a basis to make your own custom search extension.

Or adding to jitendra's answer, output the contact IDs with something like this database query:

```
SELECT * FROM civicrm_subscription_history WHERE group_id = ? AND status = "Removed" AND date > "????-??-?? ??:??:??";
```

As required, these could then be output as CSV e.g. using phpMyAdmin and then added to a group(s) via Import Contacts.